# Custom TabItem Style and Header binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, wpf-controls

I Created a style for my TabItem in the Template i added a Label and binded the Content property to The Header property of the TabItem. The label has a Foreground property that changes on IsMouseOveror Selected.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" >
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border x:Name="mainBorder" Margin="0">
                            <Border x:Name="innerBorder" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                        </Border>
                        <Label x:Name="txtHeader"  Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Padding="0" Focusable="False" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"  />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="txtHeader" Value="#FF1577D8"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="txtHeader" Value="#FF1577D8"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In window:

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab1" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Label}}}"  ></Label>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2" />
 </TabControl>
```

Tab1 Doesn't work but tab2 work perfect
I tried t Path=Foreground and (Label.Foreground) in the binding also tried Templatebinding, ... 
If i try in a new application it all works perfectly, what can be the cause?